# Python parse string for n-character format tags

Tags: python, string, format

I have a ascii format string that looks like `%s T=%lx:%lx D=%lx:%lx B=%lx:%lx`. I need to parse this string and extract the corresponding number of bytes from a data string.

another format string might look like `interrupt connected: interval=%d msec counts=%d-%d`

I looking for the best way to do this. Usually, when I would encounter things like this I would just iterate over the format string and pull out the character after the `%`

Now that there are two digits, my scheme crumbles. The fact that it crumbles probably means it wasn't that good in the first place.

Is there a good way to pick out these `%lx` tags?

`%lx` means an unsigned integer represented as hex (4 bytes)

Comment: Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html) ?

Comment: This might be an awfully complicated regex considering the possible amount of delimiters. For instance, for `something=%d ` OP apparently wants it to return `d`, but for `%1x:%1x` it is supposed to return `[1, 1]`??